# Same mysqli query but different result while using with php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two php scripts to access data from my database table.

**index.php**

```
<?php
require "init.php";
$name = "Jack";
$user_query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE employeeName like '$name';";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$user_query);

$data = array();

$no_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);


if($no_of_rows > 0)
{
    $data["error"] = TRUE;
    $data["message"] = "User Found";
    echo json_encode($data);
}

else
{
    $data["error"] = FALSE;
    $data["message"] = "User Not Found";
    echo json_encode($data);

}
?>
```

Here if I echo out the `$no_of_rows`, I get `1` which is correct since I have only one row corresponding to the name Jack.

Here is another approach to access the same data from the same table:

**test.php**

```
<?php

require "userTester.php";
$name = "Jack";


$mUser = new UserCheck();

$testResult = $mUser -> userPresent($name);

$data = array();

if($testResult == true)
{
    $data["error"] = TRUE;
    $data["message"] = "User Found";
    echo json_encode($data);
}

else
{
    $data["error"] = FALSE;
    $data["message"] = "User Not Found";
    echo json_encode($data);
}

?>
```

**userTester.php**

```
<?php
require "init.php";

class UserCheck
{

    function userPresent($name)
    {
        echo "Name = " .$name;
        $my_query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE employeeName like '$name';";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$my_query);

        echo json_encode($result);

        $num_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        echo "Rows = " .$num_of_rows;

        if($num_of_rows > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
?>
```

In this case, the **`$num_of_rows` always returns `0`**. In fact the sql query output is always null.

I am using the same db tables in both cases. I don't understand whats wrong.

**Note:-** the `init.php` is used to make the connection to the database and it works fine.

Comment: I **highly highly HIGHLY** recommmend not creating SQL queries with string concatenation.  You open yourself to all sorts of SQL injection problems later.  Create a parameterized query instead.

Comment: And you don't need to use `LIKE` in there.  `=` will do.  `LIKE` (usually) performs worse.

Comment: You use `LIKE` when you expect 0 to many results. I would also expect to see some kind of wild carding i.e. `LIKE 'Jack%'` which will find `Jack Black` and `Jack the Ripper`. If you know the column you are finding is unique then use `=` and not `like`

Comment: @RiggsFolly :- thanks for the comment .. but i don't understand why it runs in the 1st case but not in the 2nd approach !!!

Comment: Well that coud depend upon so many things you have not shown us. Also if you add some error checking code for eack mysql command you may find that something in one piece of code when wrong, but you are not checking for it

Answer (score 0):

You failed to pass in the $con variable in your method.

You must change the method signature to pass in both the name variable and the connection variable.

You are getting no results because it doesn't have a database connection.